Euclid’s “Elements” Redux Callahan's Problem 2
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan (The 13 June 2024 edition), but I'm having trouble understanding one of the exercises again. This time is one on page 107, specifically the number 5. I don't understand the question. The problem says:


Given the base of a triangle and the difference of the squares of its
sides, the locus of its vertex is a segment perpendicular to the base.


I guess, is trying to tell me that I need to demonstrate that in fact the locus is that perpendicular segment. But I don't know what vertexes are talking about, or even what means by locus of its vertex. I know that a locus is a set of all points whose location satisfies or is determined by one or more specified conditions, but what is the condition here. If someone could make it visual for me. My native language is Spanish, so sorry if I have some errors.

The condition to be satisfied is that the difference of the squares of the other two sides is constant. The locus is formed by the third vertex, the one not on the base.

HINT: Draw the altitude relative to the base and use Pythagoras' theorem.

@Intelligentipauca Thanks, I already understood the exercise.
